# Remove duplicates as well as original row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Removing duplicates is no problem, i am hitting an issue where i want to remove not only the duplicate but the original row that incurred the duplicate in a SELECT statement.

```
ItemNUMBER  ID    from_DATE   to_DATE   fancy_code
1           100   3/28/2015   4/10/2015    Z5111
2           100   4/18/2015   4/21/2015    Z5112
3           100   5/2/2015    5/5/2015     Z5111
4           100   5/31/2015   6/2/2015     Z5111
5           100   7/31/2015   8/16/2015    A400       --remove
6           100   7/31/2015   8/16/2015    A400       --remove
```

Above is my table, and --remove is what the end goal is.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `Removing` mean you want perform a DELETE or just remove them from the result?

Comment: remove them from the result

Comment: what is your query, add select query and your trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brute force method is to use window functions:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by ID, from_DATE, to_DATE, fancy_code) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt = 1;
```

The more intelligent method is to fix the query or the data that is causing the duplicates.  Of course, there are circumstances where such a fix is not possible, so you need to use the brute force method.

Answer (score 0):

In a list

```
SELECT MIN(ItemNUMBER), from_DATE, to_DATE, fancy_code
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID, from_DATE, to_DATE, fancy_code
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

If need `DELETE`

```
DELETE FROM yourTable
WHERE ItemNUMBER  NOT IN (
    SELECT MIN(ItemNUMBER) as ItemNUMBER
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY ID, from_DATE, to_DATE, fancy_code
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could select them with a join on exactly those rows.

```
SELECT ItemNUMBER, ID, from_DATE, to_DATE, fancy_code
FROM [Table] t join (
    SELECT ItemNUMBER, ID, from_DATE, to_DATE, count(1)
    FROM [Table] t
    GROUP BY ItemNUMBER, ID, from_DATE, to_DATE
    HAVING count(1) = 1
) u on (u.ItemNUMBER= t.ItemNUMBER and u.ID=t.ID 
    and u.from_DATE=t.from_DATE and u.to_DATE = t.to_DATE)
```

Adjust to taste depending on what the key is in your original table (ID would be a candidate).

Comment: having count(1) = 1 ...    select count (1) will always be 1 since restrained by having count(1) = 1

Answer (score 0):

would normally just delete the duplicitous entry

step 1: get the duplicate entries
step 2: identify itemnumbers from duplicate entries
step 3: delete those itemnumbers

```
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE itemnumber IN (SELECT
    itemNumber
  FROM table1 z
  INNER JOIN (SELECT
    fancy_code,
    id,
    from_date,
    to_date
  FROM table1 x
  GROUP BY fancy_code,
           id,
           from_date,
           to_date
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) y
    ON y.fancy_code = z.fancy_code
    AND y.id = z.id
    AND y.from_date = z.from_date
    AND y.to_date = z.to_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you reach to the repeated `ItemNUMBER` in the table, you can delete all of them by a simple `WHERE` clause.

In order to do that, you need to use an inner `JOIN` of the table itself, then by `GROUP`-ing `BY` the repeatable columns you'll reach to the the aim.

So the query can be similar to the following:

```
DELETE  theTable
WHERE   ItemNUMBER IN
(
    SELECT  t1.ItemNUMBER
    FROM    theTable t1
    JOIN    theTable t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID AND t1.from_DATE = t2.from_DATE AND t1.to_DATE = t2.to_DATE AND t1.fancy_code = t2.fancy_code
    GROUP   BY t1.ItemNUMBER
    HAVING  COUNT(t1.ItemNUMBER) > 1
)
```

Comment: where is the duplicate entry?

Comment: @maSTArHiAn, The select query returns the duplicated records

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do it by using CTE and count(*).

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT fkledgeraccid,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID,from_DATE,to_DATE,fancy_code) AS row
  FROM TABLE1
) 
Select * from cte where row=1
```